# How can I parse JSON arrays in postgresql?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.14, and have a column in a table that contains JSON arrays that I need to parse for their contents.

Using a select I can see that the structure of the JSON is of this kind:

```
SELECT rule_results from table limit 5;
```

Result:

```
[{"rule_key":"applicant_not_lived_outside_eu"},{"rule_key":"family_assets_exceed_limit"},{"rule_key":"owned_a_deed"}]

[]

[]

[{"rule_key":"family_category","details":"apply_with_parents_under_25"}]

[]
```

I have been unable to create an SQL command to give me the values of the **rule_key** keys.

I've attempted to use the documentation for json-functions in postgresql to find a solution from
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

```
SELECT rule_results::json->'rule_key' as results from table;
```

This gives me null values only.

```
SELECT jsonb_object_keys(rule_results::jsonb) from table;
```

This results in the error msg "*cannot call jsonb_object_keys on a scalar*", which seems to mean that the query is limited to a single row.

This looks simple enough, an array with key:value pairs, but somehow the answer eludes me. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What result are you expecting? Every value in one row? All values in one array?

Comment: I am hoping to be able to have every value in one row. At the moment I am trying to figure out how to get to the key pairs inside the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a8e44f6e2772a69e0dda18c80d610417)

Different solutions are possible. It depends on what you are expecting finally. But all solutions would use the function json_array_elements(). This expands every element into one row. With that you can do whatever you want.

This results in one row per value:

```
SELECT 
    value -> 'rule_key'
FROM
    data,
    json_array_elements(rule_results)
```